# How to privately delay a command in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a very basic AI for a little game I'm making. I have a goblin that I want to change its position whenever it needs to, but on a 500 millisecond delay as to make it more avoidable.

I've tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int gX = 18, gY = 12;

int goblinAI() {
  if(gX - x > 0) {
    Sleep(500);
    cMap[gY][gX] = '.';
    gX--;
  } else if(gX - x < 0) {
    Sleep(500);
    cMap[gY][gX] = '.';
    gX++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I thought this code would work, but it turns out I overlooked something. Now it is going to sleep for the rest of the program because its being called with goblinAI();. How can I 'privately' call Sleep(); as to make it only sleep inside of itself instead of 'infecting' the whole program?

game.cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

char cMap[21][34] = {
    "#################################",
    "#@..............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#...............................#",
    "#################################"
};

bool running = true;
bool alive = true;

int x = 1, y = 1;
int health = 100;
int eX, eY; // exit x and y

#include "controls.cpp" // includes the controls file after the instantation of the variables in which it uses
#include "goblinAI.cpp"

int main() {
    while (running) {

    controls();
    goblinAI();

        //cMap[eX][eY] = 'E';
    cMap[y][x] = '@';
    cMap[gY][gX] = 'G';

    system("cls");

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            cout << cMap[i] << endl;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            cout << "HP: " << health << endl;
        }

        if(cMap[y][x] == cMap[gY][gX]) {
            health--;
        }
        if(health == 0) {
            alive = true;
            running = false;
        }

        system("pause>nul");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you might be asking about threading.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm quite new to C++.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how your game operates. I'm guessing it's a "loop" of reading player input from the keyboard/controller, computing AI, collision detection, and rendering something to the screen.  If that's the case...

Instead of `Sleep`ing, call `GoblinAI` as often as possible (once per frame) and use a timestamp to decide if it's an appropriate moment to "move" the object.

```
DWORD lastGoblinMoveTime = 0;

int goblinAI() {

   DWORD dwTime = GetTickCount();
   DWORD elapsed = dwTime - lastGoblinMoveTime;

   if (elapsed > 500) {

      lastGoblinMoveTime = dwTime;

      if(gX - x > 0) {
        cMap[gY][gX] = '.';
        gX--;
      } else if(gX - x < 0) {
        cMap[gY][gX] = '.';
        gX++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This isn't working. I think it would be a good idea to show you the rest of my code. I'm updating my current post to show the game.cpp code.

My game works by updating an array of characters each time a button is pressed. I think you're code would work with a game that ran frame by frame.

Comment: This still isn't working. Is there a way to delay the action by a frame? The only reason I put 500 was because I wanted a delay but not something unreasonable.

Comment: @clonts  You need to check for a keypress and not wait for a keypress.  Then the program can loop every 500 milliseconds and only update the screen when the key is pressed - that way you can do things while waiting for the keypress.  If you are using Windows look into conio.h at the kbhit() function.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I would do that, but it gives a flashing effect which is not very pleasant to look at. Surely there's a way to delay it by a frame? I'll try your way as well though.

Comment: @clonts You can't do anything while you are waiting for a keypress.  I'm NOT suggesting you update the screen each loop - you only need to do that when a key is pressed (or when the goblin moves).

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I ended up rolling a random number between 0 and 2 and if it's equal to 1 the goblin will move towards the player. Works perfectly for now - will probably change it to move every other move later.